# Python equivalent of Lua coroutines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lua, coroutine, equivalent

I've been working on a brick-stacking game in Lua. The core game code uses coroutines in the main game loop, to wait for events such as an input press, or a timer finishing. I'm considering switching it over to Python, to make it much more portable, but I can't figure out how to use `async` and `await` properly, to be equivalent to Lua's coroutines.

The following code is a simple coroutine example in Lua. How would I go about writing the same in Python, while behaving the same?

```
function myCoroutine(arg1)

    print(arg1)
    local newValue = coroutine.yield(arg1 + 2)
    print(newValue)

    local lastValue = coroutine.yield(arg1 * newValue^2)
    print(lastValue)


end


local co = coroutine.create(myCoroutine)

local success, yield1 = coroutine.resume(co, 10)
local success, yield2 = coroutine.resume(co, yield1 * 2)
coroutine.resume(co, yield2 / 3)
```

Expected output:

```
10
24
1920
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually very similar:

```
def myCoroutine():

    arg1 = (yield)
    print(arg1)

    newValue = (yield arg1 + 2)
    print(newValue)

    lastValue = (yield arg1 * newValue ** 2)
    print(lastValue)

co = myCoroutine()
co.send(None) # "prime" the coroutine
try:
    yield1 = co.send(10)
    yield2 = co.send(yield1 * 2)
    co.send(yield2 // 3)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought it would have to do with `asyncio` but I didn't know about `yield`

Comment: Correct my if I'm wrong, but those are just stackless coroutines, right? if so, they aren't nearly as powerful as Luas stackful coroutines, and only a partial replacement.